# What is this original version of Tetris called?

Tags: game-identification, tetris

I'd like to play the original Tetris I played near the end of the 80's, the Arcade game:

[image: Tetris Title Screen]
[image: Tetris In-game]

Does anyone know exactly what this version of Tetris is called?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- **Title**: Tetris (set 1)
- **Developer**: Atari Games
- **Release(arcade)**: [February 1989](https://atariemailarchive.org/thread/lawsuits-with-nintendo-810)
- **Platform**: JAMMA (arcade) with Atari
- **Playfield dimensions**: 10w x 20h

You can play it with **MAME** (Multiple Arcade Machine Emulator). This emulator have open source code, you can download build or sources [here](http://www.mamedev.org/release.php).
<sub>*(as questions about direct links to ROM are considered as an offtopic, I can't provide such link)*</sub>

More info [here](http://www.arcade-museum.com/game_detail.php?game_id=10081).

Comment: Found it, as you can see :)

Answer (score 6):

This version of Tetris is from the Atari (1988).
[image]

https://retro-video-gaming.com/2015/04/13/atari-tetris-arcade-from-1988/

I think it was based off the old Тетрис Tetris (Soviet mind game/challenge)
[image: Тетрис Tetris]

Comment: Might be right, tetris is russian in origin. Cool floppy disk and diskette

Comment: Atari Tetris was not based off the Spectrum HoloByte version. It was however sub-licensed from their sister company called Mirrorsoft.

Both of these versions were the first commercial releases on their respective platforms and regions.

Comment: Thanks for the soundtrack! (Did not notice it the first time!)